# Latex \textbar is printed as 'j' in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, latex

I am trying to use `\textbar` in my plot. Instead I find a j. A minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlabel("this should be a bar $\\rightarrow \\textbar$")
plt.savefig("test.png")
```

This is the output:

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

`\textbar` should not be called in mathmode.

```
ax.set_xlabel("this should be a bar $\\rightarrow$ \\textbar")
```